# How to use Material.io outlined icons in css pseudoelements (::before)?

Tags: css, icons, material-design, material-ui

I'm trying to add [Material.io](https://material.io/tools/icons/?icon=visibility&style=outline) icon to a button using ::before, but it only displays the icon filled.

There are no guides about how to set the icon outlined.

This is my code:

```
.view-site:before{
    content: "\E8F4";
    font-family: 'Material Icons';
}
```

How do i display the outlined icon?

Answer (score 1):

Google claim the new themes feature weeks ago but apparently there's no clue on how to use outlined, sharp, rounded and two tone icons.

I believe the only reference we got is here:
https://github.com/google/material-design-icons/issues/773

Answer (score 0):

I believe you missed the dot before the CSS rule. Here is the fixed solution:

```css
.view-site:before {
  content: "\E8F4";
  font-family: 'Material Icons';
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<i class="view-site">
  
</i>
```

Comment: I have no problem to use outline icons as a HTML tag. I'm looking to use it as a pseudoclass (::before).

Comment: The dot missing was a typo.
I'm able to show the icon, but it isn't outlined. Your answer is what i'm doing, except that view-site is a div instead of an i element.